# Are questions in the style of code review SE allowed?

Tags: discussion

[CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) lets you post a section of code (usually <100 lines) and other users can review it. Is this allowed in Music P+T SE?

Examples:

- What are the difficulties of the piece Moonlight Sonata 3<sup>rd</sup> ?
- A Romantic Chopin-style piece {Explain more and post composition}

Comment: To add to Dom's comment, we'd (OK, I) would love to hear more of users' actual music here - and I agree that [chat] seems a good place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Code review" in the most literal sense is already allowed, since [`lilypond`](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond) questions occur here fairly frequently. But for us it's less "review" and more "how do I do this?" or "what am I doing wrong?"

As for your two examples, they both seem too opinion-based to succeed here. Even though we do allow some subjective questions (see the ["What Not to Ask" page](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)), your two examples still seem to stretch the limits. Difficulty is subjective, so there is no right answer for your Beethoven question. And your Chopin-style question is a little unclear to me, but it still seems completely opinion-based if we're to "review" the piece and offer suggestions (which, again, are completely subjective).

Comment: I'd like to point out that chat can be used in general for discussion questions like this that are too subjective for the main site so you can get some idea of what others feel and why.